# How do I set a path variable in my bashrc file from my command line to use python 3

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow

Using a :

- macOS High Sierra version 10.13.5
- python version is 3.70

I am trying to install tensorflow on a macOS with Virtualenv. I am following the instructions from:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package

but I got stuck when installing tensorflow and the packages that tensorflow requires with the following command :

```
(targetDirectory)$ pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow     # for Python 3.n
```

and was given the following error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow.

so I tried installing again with the following code :

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade tfBinaryURL  # Python 3.n
```

with the URL I am using : https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl

but that URL was only for python 3.4, 3.5, 3.6 and I received this error :

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tfBinaryURL (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tfBinaryURL

Now I am trying to figure out how to create a path variable in my bashrc file to use python 3 from the command line, so I can finish installing tensorflow.

Comment: This is an ongoing issue: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9815. Seems like 3.7 isn't fully supported, so I would recommend either waiting or using a different version a python.

Comment: thank you and it was exactly what you said. i uninstalled python 3.7 and installed python 3.6.6 and it worked!